# Display Categories on x-axis for Highcharts spline with x and y data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My data needs to have an x and a y value, because I want to show the x value when the user hovers over the chart.

I only want to show a limited amount of labels on the x-axis though, which is why I am using categories. I keep getting `Highcharts error #19` though, because the chart apparently tries to use the x-values provided in the data array.

I've played around with using `type: 'datetime'`, since I am working with timestamps but I can't position the labels properly in this case and want to use categories instead.

I've created a jsfiddle to explain my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6wrj37/

Instead of just the first and last x-value being display, I want my categories array

`categories: [
      '1453417200000',
      '1456873200000',
      '1460325600000',
      '1463781600000',
      '1467237600000',
      '1470693600000',
      '1474149600000',
      '1477605600000',
      '1481065200000',
      '1484521200000',
      '1487977200000'
    ],`

to be displayed as labels on the x-axis.

How should I go about this? Is it even possible to use categories when my chart's data has x and y values?

Comment: Hi! Did you consider `datetime` xAxis and `tickPositions` instead? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zbv3jaxd/2/ If you could attach a screenshot what is the expected result, that would help. Anyway, you said, you work with timestamps, so categories are a big NO :) Using `tickPositions` in categories is also a solution, but I'm afraid you are trying to reinvent the wheel :) See: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/htznqmbu/2/

Comment: `tickPosition` seems to do the trick! My main problem with using `datetime` was that I couldn't seem to center the labels without using some kind of function to determine the ticks (as seen here https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=149034#p149034), though I guess I'm doing something very similar to determine the values I used for my categories already anyways, now that I think about it.

But `tickPosition` seems to work best in my situation anyways.

Thank you! Much appreciated.